# Query returning strange and different results on different servers

Tags: mysql

**Never mind, sorry for wasting your time, after closer inspection there where indeed not such cases in my live data. When I first asked my client there should've been some of them. They where wrong and I was to fast to blame MySQL.**

**The Situation**

In my application the following query is run:

```
SELECT s.*, c.company_name, c.kvk_number 
FROM wp_kvk_statements as s 
LEFT JOIN wp_kvk_companies as c ON s.company_id = c.id 
WHERE s.status < 2 AND c.status = 1 
ORDER BY company_id, s.year DESC
```

**The problem**

On my dev server this query correctly returns all rows where the status in wp_kvk_statements is less then 2 (i.e. 0 or 1). For the companies with status 1 in the wp_kvk_companies table.

But on my live server only rows where the status in wp_kvk_statements is 1 are returned, as if the c.status = 1 is interpreted wrong.

**The question**

Why does this happen and how can I solve this.

**Background Info**

Development server MySQL export (this is where it works):

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.10.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Dec 03, 2012 at 01:22 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.20
-- PHP Version: 5.3.10

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_kvk_companies`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_kvk_companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `industry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `kvk_number` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `last_crawled` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_kvk_statements`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_kvk_statements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `bought` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `analyzed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`company_id`,`year`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Live server MySQL export (this is where it is broken):

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Dec 03, 2012 at 02:25 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.9
-- PHP Version: 5.3.17

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `deb51918_annuall`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_kvk_companies`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_kvk_companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `industry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `kvk_number` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `last_crawled` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_kvk_statements`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_kvk_statements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `bought` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `analyzed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`company_id`,`year`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Have you tried to reverse the test? c.status = 1 before the s.status < 2?

Comment: can you provide some example of rows? (included and excluded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query does what it is supposed to do. By the way, the `LEFT` is useless there, the join is converted into an `INNER` join because the `WHERE` clase includes a `c.status = 1` condition. SO, your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT s.*, c.company_name, c.kvk_number 
FROM wp_kvk_statements as s 
INNER JOIN wp_kvk_companies as c ON s.company_id = c.id 
WHERE s.status < 2 AND c.status = 1 
ORDER BY company_id, s.year DESC ;
```

You further say: "But on my live server only rows where the status in wp_kvk_statements is 1 are returned, ..."

Do you have any rows in the live server that have `wp_kvk_statements.status` not equal to 1? That additionally have a related row in `wp_kvk_companies` table with `c.status=1`?

I guess not. My second guess is that you are misinterpreting what the query should return (LEFT/INNER confusion maybe?).

If the live and test server return different results, you are either have different data in the two servers or you are running (slightly) different queries.